# Multiple friend selector in Facebook App

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I just started with Facebook APIs a couple of hours ago. I am trying to build a app for a page (which will be used on the page only, and not on FB side) where the users will select some of the friends in their friend list and I need to save which users did they selected.

I see FB does provide something like this (Legacy FBML) but I am unsure of how to use it or its exactly what I want. Other than that, I have the option to just display the friends list in a similar interface on page and then get it done (I already have them in an array). But the Facebook like multiple friend selector would be great! Won't have to deal with searching and styling that much.

So what would be the best option to achieve this (I am using PHP SDK).

I am describing my requirements as follows:

- User must be login into FB to do anything on the page
- Login + Permissions Dialog box for App
- Select friends among the friend list (lets say good friends), this is what I need to save.
- Then an option to share the page with your friends (status/message?) so that they can do the same too.

Pardon me if I am missing something very obvious as I just started with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this jQuery to plugin do what I want - http://mike.brevoort.com/2010/08/10/introducing-the-jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector-plugin/index.html

I am starting with JS SDK as of now, not using PHP SDK anymore!